# Logic for passing variable number of parameters to XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing

I need to develop an application that will periodically check data from a XML feed , process it and take appropriate actions like notifying the users etc but mostly used to generate and view a report. This xml feed basically checks the uptime, downtime of applications.

Here are the steps that i am following:

1. I am downloading a xml file from a remote location to my own server.
2. Check which applications to monitor from a properties file .
3. Transform it to html using a XSLT and mail the html page.

Now this XML feed also contains applications that need not be monitored and is checked using the properties file in java. The application that is monitored can be added later on.

So is there any way to have this included in the xsl file as well? (I can pass parameters from java to xslt as well , but the number of params will be variable. I am grouping the app names and passing it using two params , but stuck because these values cannot be compared using the `xsl:for-each` iterator of the XML feed file.)

**EDIT:**

```
<begin last-update="12/16/2011 06:18:31 am">
    <application id="1" name="xyz" last-update="12/16/2011 6:16:03 AM">
        <node2 code="normal">
            <childnodes></childnodes>
            <childnodes></childnodes>
        </node2>

    </application>
    <application id="2" name="abc" last-update="12/14/2011 6:16:03 AM">
        ... Same as before
</application>
</begin>
```

This is the xml feed . i am iterating through this xml ..i need to check the name attribute in the application node .. below is the xsl code

```
<xsl:for-each select="begin/application">
<!-- Need this to be fetched dynamically using xsl params -->
<xsl:if test="@name='abc' or @name=xyz' >
<tr width="100%" style="border:solid 1px black;">
<td  style="text-align:center; vertical-align:center;">DATA</td>
<td  style="text-align:center; vertical-align:center;">DATA</td>
<td  style="text-align:center; vertical-align:center;">DATA</td>
</tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Currently name attributes are hardcoded .. i need to use these from the parameters list passed from the java code- the parameter string being **app1,app2** and parameters in node set as

```
<root>
<application @name="ABC"></application>
<application @name="XYZ"></application>
</root>
```

The question is how do i iterate through the params , as i would also need the iteration for the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use JAXB to provide you with a Java representation of your XML data. Then you can playaround with the data in your Java code using your properties file (or whatever may replace your properties file with in the future, like a database table), and then just create your HTML output with a JSP/Velocity/`<insert favourite view tech here>`

This will probably be a more flexible design than trying to shoe horn everything into XSL

Answer (score 2):

The way to pass "multiple parameters" to a transformation is to pass a single parameter, that is an XML element (tree), whose children elements will be processed and treated as the actual (logical) parameters by the transformation.

Pass something like this:

```
<params>
 <param name="p1"> some subtree/<param>

.  .  .  .  

 <param name="pk"> some subtree/<param>
<params>
```

Comment: Or in XSLT 2.0, you can pass a sequence of strings (or a sequence of numbers etc) assuming your processor API allows this - in Saxon, any Java Iterable should be OK.

Comment: tried this years ago. But to no avail ...
but a wrokaround, could be that you pass a parameter - string.
this string will use document() function, that i turn get your XML parameter ?
I know it is a two phase logic and requires filesystem - but for now it works ...

Comment: @Mike: You probably only have tried passing the parameter from the command-line. Every XSLT processor of a more than dosen I am using, has its own API that allows more complex structures to be passed as parameters -- including whole parsed XML documents or their individual elements. Just read the documentation of your XSLT processor.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev : Tried the path of passing xml tree , but then got stuck when comparing the xml tree nodes with the actual xml file . (I am using a for-each to iterate and test conditions in the xml file) . Basically if there was a way to iterate both the xml parameter tree as well as the xml file this is the best option.

Comment: @MichaelKay : Tried Passing a sequence of strings , used tokenize to separate them , but then again stuck with the task of iterating and comparing these parameters with the xml feed file.

Comment: @user1102065: Your question is about the ways of passing undefined number of parameters to the transformation and you got good answers. Now you are introducing a new question -- please, ask it as a new question and not as a comment. As you have successfully passed and accessed the multiple parameters, please, be ethical and accept what you consider to be the best/most useful answer. In the future, when you have accumulated 50 points, you will have the right to upvote any other answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev : Apologies , but i believe that i had written this scenario in my first post itself . The question could have been framed differently , but honestly , i do not think this is a new question. if you refer to the text in parenthesis in the last para of my post you will find that i have discussed the above scenario..

Comment: @user1102065: What you are saying inside the parenthesis doesn't make sense unless you provide a complete XML document, the complete wanted result and the required properties of the transformation, At present you haven't provided any of these. Please, edit your question and provide all relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I was able to do this.
Instead of passing parameters, I created an XML file and using the document function read that file in a template.
This template was called inside from the for-each of the main document.
Here, I passed parameters to the template, iterated through the XML file and did whatever I was supposed to do.

Uhm , in case someone is stuck in a stupid situation like me, where they did not think through before investing a significant amount of time.
JAXB is the best way to go through.
I did implement the JAXB solution and its quite simple.
But, since the xslt is currently satisfying my requirement I am going with XSLT.

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="begin/application">
<xsl:call-template name="doSome">
    <xsl:with-param name="appname" select="@name" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:template name="doSome">
    <xsl:param name="appname" />
    <xsl:for-each select="document('file:///E:/LOG/list.xml')/root/application">
        <xsl:if test="@name=$appname">                  
            ... do whatever you want to do
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```